# Facebook API: getting a like list of another user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My task is to retrieve a page like list of another user than me. Can this be done by a Facebook API? I'm trying through Graph API, and get page likes lists of public institutions like a public agency. But if I want to get it from an individual person I fail, there's simply no page likes list in the API data I get.

Comment: Please share your code with us.

Comment: Have the user grant user_likes permission to your app and then call /me/likes